# UTF-8 Character set CentOS PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, centos

I've a problem with the utf-8, I'm trying to show russian characters over my page, but I'm getting ???? instead of those russian characters.

I tried to modify .htaccess like AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 but didn't work.

I also observed that when I try to show characters using .html extension (no php) it works fine, but with the php file is shows ?????.

**server details**

php 5.3.16
centos release 6.3

I've similar problem as here

http://remository.com/forum/func,view/id,18483/catid,24/

Thanks

Comment: wiki says centos doesn't include support for utf-8 characters     "The Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) library that ships with some (all?) versions Red Hat/CentOS 5 does not include support for the UTF-8 character set."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding these lines in main php.ini worked for me

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=6
```