# Wordpress character encoding Issue when editing posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When I edit a post in Wordpress using the 'Text' mode and enter special characters via using & and euro; for instance for the Euro sign, things work fine. I publish the post and the characters appear ok on my site.

If however I try to go back and edit the page, in the text-mode all special characters are displayed as they are and the encoding is gone (so & euro; is displayed as €).

Here's the strange thing. If I edit a post, go into text-edit mode rather than visual edit and enter a character code and THEN switch to visual mode WITHOUT saving or publishing and THEN switch back to the text edit mode tab, all my character codes are gone and in text edit mode IMMEDIATELY. So & euro; becomes € in text edit mode straight away. This happens both in Chrome and Safari browsers.

On my server I have several Wordpress sites with various WP versions, this happens to WP version 4.4 as well as older versions. My PHP version is 5.5.30.

I checked the following without success:

- changed the WP-config file UTF-8 settings and DB collate lines. Deleted them, defined UTF-8 specifically etc. Didn't work.
- checked MySql in phpMyAdmin. Server connection collation is UTF8_general_ci. Tried utf8mb4_general_ci as well.
- some WP site are UTF8_general, some are UTF8mb4, both have same problem.
- my pages are being served with the following header:

  meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

What else can I check?
Can it be a Mac related browser issue as it happens straight away when switching from text to visual mode without saving or updating?

Comment: And if you view the source, do the € shown as &euro ?

Comment: The HTML source you mean? When saved at first and served correctly, I see the actual characters in the HTML source, not the &euro or &iuml for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem finally. This post answered it for me: [UTF-8 Character set CentOS PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104615/utf-8-character-set-centos-php)

Basically, my PHP.ini settings were wrong.

Setting the following in php.ini helped me out:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=6
```